# scsitools (specifically scsiinfo) for Fedora / Centos

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, scsi

I am looking for the scsitools package for fedora. Ubuntu has such a .deb named "scsitools". Specifically I need to find out the vendor, serial number etc. of hard disks connected to a machine.

`scsiinfo -i <device>` and `scsiinfo -s <device>` seem to do the task nicely on debian based systems, but I was unable to find a .rpm package.

Where can I find this package, or is there an other way on Fedora to get this information?

Comment: oh well, never mind. I just copied the executable from a ubuntu machine to my fedora machine and it "just works".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`sdparm`](http://sg.danny.cz/sg/sdparm.html) which should be available for all major distributions.
Maybe you also find some information in `/proc/scsi`.